# SOLR: ms function in query does not convert date to long

Tags: solr, solr4

ms function in query on field does return Date,  not milliseconds

q=*:*&fl=ms(last_activity),last_activity,ms(2014-11-13T15:51:40.054Z)
=>

```
<doc>
<date name="last_review_activity_register">2014-10-05T13:14:55.828Z</date>
<date name="ms(last_review_activity_register)">2014-10-05T13:14:55.828Z</date>
<long name="ms(2014-11-13T15:51:40.054Z)">1415893900054</long>
</doc>
```

Constant converted fine. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What type is the field last_review_activity_register?

Comment: <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this solution: Instead calling

```
q=:&fl=ms(last_activity)
```

use the two argument version of ms function:

```
q=:&fl=ms(last_activity,1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)
```

What is returned is last_activity's number of milliseconds since the epoch.